# Associating header files with both C and C++

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two folders on my computer

```
/home/zee/projects/c/
/home/zee/projects/cpp/
```

the c folder has my C projects obviously, and then the cpp folder has my C++ projects. I want visual studio code to treat files with the `.h` extension as C headers if they are in a directory inside the c folder but also treat files with that extension inside the cpp folder as C++ headers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are most likely in different workspaces.

You can change the `files.associations` setting per workspace

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_can-i-map-additional-file-extensions-to-a-language